# Azure machine learning specify input size

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I just started using Azure ML and I'm trying to figure out how to specify an input size for the models. Specifically, I have a big training set of data, but I want to input only 250 records at a time into the PCA algorithm. It seems like all I can do is hook the entire data set into the PCA module.

I know how to partition the data for X-validation, but I want a partition (say 10000 records) to only feed 250 records at a time to the model.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a SQL Transform to select a subset to feed it to the next module.

Comment: How would you do that iteratively to break a partiiton into subsets and feed all the subsets?